# Pass value from one controller to another from the view

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I have a browse page and a detail page. I also have browse controller and detail controller. The browse page displays a list of persons. When the user clicks on a person link, I'm passing `person.id` to the detail page as a query string parameter. It's all good here.

Now, I have another view where the browse and the detail should be in the same page. How do I pass the `person.id` from one div (with `ng-controller='BrowseCtrl'`) to another div (with `ng-controller='DetailCtrl'`)?

The goal is to make the controllers as generic as possible.

```
 function BrowseCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.persons = db.getPersons();
        $scope.getPerson = function (personId) {
            $location.path('/person').search({
                id: personId;
            });
        };
    }

    function DetailCtrl($scope, $location) {
        $scope.person = db.getPerson($routeParams.id);
    }

    //singlepage.html
     <div ng-controller="BrowseCtrl"> 
          <ul id="thumbList">
             <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
               <img ng-src="{{person.photo}}" ng-click="getPerson(person.id)"/>
             </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="DetailCtrl">
       Name: {{person.name}} 
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass the person.id as query string param? Surely you are building a single page app, you shouldn't need more than one page.

Comment: The URL looks something like `index.html#view/person?id=1`. Should it have been `index.html#view/person/1`? If so, how do I grab the person id? Let's assume I don't pass the query string. How do I invoke a method in `DetailCtrl` from a view that is within the scope of `BrowseCtrl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method you can use is [`$broadcast()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24broadcast) and [`$on()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24on) to communicate between your two controllers.

```
function BrowseCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.persons = db.getPersons();
    $scope.getPerson = function (personId) {
       $rootScope.$broadcast("personId", personId);
    };
}


function DetailCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$on("personId", function(event, id){
       $scope.person = db.getPerson(id);
    }
}
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/6g5QT/)**

But ideally creating a service that is shared between the two controllers is the better way to handle things overall.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've been hearing a lot about services lately. I'll look it up. My goal is to make the controllers as generic as possible to handle multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside 1st controller's scope:

```
        var div = document.querySelector('#Controller2');
        var scope = angular.element(div).scope();
        scope.myVal = true; //access the value of the 2nd controller
```